# Generate select options using page titles

Tags: php, jquery

I am creating a CMS website and I am new to the jquery scene. I have a form and I am trying to dynamically generate a select option where the options are page titles of the pages on the website. Instead of me writing them in the `<options> </options>` section of the form, I want to have them dynamically selected, say on button click on the home page, it redirect me to the form page where the page name will automatically select `Home` from the options, if that's possible. How can i archive this using jquery?

**This is the code that dynamically creates the page names:**

```
<?php
    $app = JFactory::getApplication();
    $menu = $app->getMenu();
    $active = $menu->getActive();
    $class = $active->alias;
    ?>
  <body class="is-preloaded" id="<?php echo $class; ?>">
```

**The form**

```
 <form action="">
          <section>
            <select name="page name" id="page-name">
              <option value="" selected disabled> --Choose event location --</option>
            </select>
          </section>
          <section>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Add Event</button>
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Cancel</button>
          </section>
        </div>
      </form>
```

May you help me out with the jquery code for this?

Comment: You should add more info, this part "where the options are page titles" is very unclear.

Comment: please check the edited version

Comment: Where does that data come from? Why not generate such data using PHP, where you have access to all data?

Comment: @NicoHaase please explain more if possible.

Comment: Yeah, please explain more. Where do these page titles come from? Why do you want to use jQuery for this?

Comment: I am building my websites using joomla. so when i create an article, the article name becomes the page name. As for jquery, most scripts are jquery so i was looking for help in those lines. If not jquery then what can i use?